# Doesn't await axios requests when i use in for loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, async-await, axios

I am trying to get productInfo by productId from backend. I am iterating over productId and fetching data with axios. But it only iterates one element for every compile. How can i iterate all of them in one execution ?

```
const useBasket = (location) => {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    const [descriptions, setDescriptions] = useState([]); 
    console.log("ACCOUNT ID:", location.location.state.accountId);
    useEffect(() => {
        const getBasket = async () => {
            const basketResponse = await Axios.get("http://localhost:8084/accountId/" + location.location.state.accountId);
            setProducts(basketResponse.data.products);
        };
        const getProductInfo = async (props) => {
            console.log("INSIDE getProductInfo:",props);
            const productResponse = await Axios.get("http://localhost:8081/product/" + props).catch(err => console.log(err));
            setDescriptions([...descriptions,productResponse.data.description]);  
        }
        getBasket();
        for(let i = 0; i < products.length; i++){
            console.log("INSIDE FOR:",products[i]);
            getProductInfo(products[i]);
        } 
        
    }, []); 
    console.log("DESCRIPTIONS:",descriptions);
    return { descriptions }; 
};
```

I tried to put the for loop inside of a async function. After that i made await the function call inside of the for loop.

I also put loading section when data is not complete it won't return.

But none of them worked.

Comment: You have to await `getBasket()`

Comment: @jabaa it still won't work because state updates in the next render cycle

Comment: @jabaa But the main problem is not with setting the state. The problem is to read the state.  With the implementation above there is no easy way to observe the result of `setProducts` in the loop. Even if OP uses a nested function and awaits on `getBasket`, the `products` array will be empty in the loop (because of the closure).

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Now I see, what Konrad means. Yes, that won't work.

Comment: @jabaa It seems I have responded to the removed comment. Sorry :)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I removed it, because I wasn't sure and you explained it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

State updates are asynchronous and the closure captures the current value of each of your state variables (which won't change inside the same closure). You should directly access the values from the response instead and use `await` to ensure the request for products finishes before getting the descriptions.

Here is one way to implement it:

```js
const getBasket = async () => {
    const basketResponse = await Axios.get("http://localhost:8084/accountId/" + location.location.state.accountId);
    return basketResponse.data.products;
};
const getProductInfo = (props) => {
    return Axios.get("http://localhost:8081/product/" + props).then(r => r.data.description);
}
(async () => {
    const newProducts = await getBasket();
    setProducts(newProducts);
    const newDescriptions = await Promise.all(newProducts.map(getProductInfo));
    setDescriptions([...descriptions, ...newDescriptions]);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

`getBasket` is an async function. Execution does not wait for it to finish/return before continuing. This means your for loop is referencing a products state variable this is unlikely to have been updated.

There are a number of ways around this (assuming you cannot simply modify the product fetch to include descriptions):

- You could wrap `getBasket` in a promise and await it before iterating.
- You could combine your `getProductInfo` function within `getBasket` and iterate `basketResponse.data.products`
- You could wrap getProductInfo in its own useEffect which is executed when products are updated i.e.

  ```
  useEffect(() => {

     const getProductInfo = async (props) => {
        const productResponse = await Axios.get("http://localhost:8081/product/" + props).catch(err => console.log(err));
        setDescriptions((prev) => [...prev, productResponse.data.description]);  
    }

    for(let i = 0; i < products.length; i++){
        getProductInfo(products[i]);
    }
  }, [products]);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that can be changed here, and they all boil down to how to handle stuff that doesn't happen immediately, like:

1. calling async functions that send api requests (you do wait for axios to return the value, but you don't wait for the whole async function to finish, so then the for loop part starts executing before the request is finished)
2. using state after setState (this isn't instantaneous, setState calls are batched and executed together, it's so quick that the only time you notice it when you write code that uses the state after a setState call)

Now, there might be different ways to solve this, but here's the solution with least changes:

```
const useBasket = (location) => {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    const [descriptions, setDescriptions] = useState([]);
    console.log("ACCOUNT ID:", location.location.state.accountId);
    
    const getBasket = async () => {
        const basketResponse = await Axios.get("http://localhost:8084/accountId/" + location.location.state.accountId);
        setProducts(basketResponse.data.products);
        return basketResponse.data.products;
    };
    const getProductInfo = async (props) => {
        console.log("INSIDE getProductInfo:", props);
        const productResponse = await Axios.get("http://localhost:8081/product/" + props).catch(err => console.log(err));
        setDescriptions([...descriptions, productResponse.data.description]);
    }

    useEffect(async () => {
        const prods = await getBasket();
        for (let i = 0; i < prods.length; i++) {
            console.log("INSIDE FOR:", prods[i]);
            getProductInfo(prods[i]);
        }

    }, []);

    console.log("DESCRIPTIONS:", descriptions);
    return { descriptions };
};
```

1. the `getBasket` and `getProductInfo` were moved outside the `useEffect` (optional, for readability)
2. `getBasket` also returns the data when it is done
3. an `await` was added before the `getBasket` call
4. the for loop uses the returned list instead of the one from state

Comment: `useEffect(async () => {` you can't do it like this. `useEffect` expects the function to possibly return a cleanup function, not a Promise.  Also `getProductInfo` might finish in different order than started. So the ordering in `descriptions` won't match the `products`. Will likely cause some issues down the line.